# special kind of synchronising two directories using a skript on linux

Tags: ruby, linux, rsync

I'm using a linux server at home to store my photos in full resolution in a dir called pics/FULL. To speed up delivery through my dlna-server (minidlna) I prepared a second dir pics/SMALL with same subdirectory-names and same filenames. But all pics in this dir are converted in a smaller resolution. I did this via a small skript that creates SMALL and then iterates through all subdirs in FULL and converts every pic.

But FULL is my main-dir. So if I change a pic or path (delete, rotate, add an additional one to an existing subdir, move a pic and so on), I always do this in pics/FULL. Now I need a skript, that just detects changes between SMALL and FULL (e.g. new pics/subdirs, pics with a FULL-timestamp newer than same pic in SMALL). This skript should run nightly.

I could write a skript (prefer Ruby) to do this but I wonder if there is already a method or gem to do this out there? Similar to rsync without coping differences but calling a skript for each difference?

Perhaps someone with a nice hint for an existing skript?

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use the [rb-inotify](https://github.com/nex3/rb-inotify) gem (which is a wrapper for the linux [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) kernel subsystem, which gives your app events on filesystem changes).

Using it, you can monitor your `FULL` directory and mirror every action into the `SMALL` dir.

The following stub should get you going:

```
require 'rb-inotify'

notifier = INotify::Notifier.new
# you might want events like :moved_to etc. - have a look at the documentation :)
notifier.watch("path/to/FULL", :create, :modify, :delete) do |e|
  puts e.absolute_name # gives you the absolute path to the file/directory, which caused the event
  puts e.flags # gives you the event types that caused this event (e.g. :modified)
  if e.flags.include? :create
    if e.flags.include? :isdir
      # create matching dir in SMALL
    else
      # create new image in SMALL
    end
  elsif e.flags.include? :modify
    # generate new SMALL image if it's not a dir
  elsif e.flags.include? :deleted
    # delete matching dir/file in SMALL
  end
end

notifier.run # loops forever and waits for filesystem events
# alternatively use
notifier.process # blocks untils first filesystem changes was processed
```

Please have a look at the [gem documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/nex3/rb-inotify) and the [inotify documentation](http://www.tin.org/bin/man.cgi?section=7&topic=inotify) (to see which event-types are possible).

Comment: Thanks, you kicked me in right direction. Inotify will help solving my problem.